# How to check for common objects between 2 generic lists

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have 2 lists that I need to check for common objects that are being passed to a generic wrapper.

The first list (`selList`) is a typed entity list.  The `ID` field in this list is different, based on what the base type for the list being created.

The second list (`masterList`) is an anonymous `IList` that I know has 2 properties {ID, DESC} - ID (could be int or string), and description (string).  I can get the value of the ID property in this list.

I would like to return an extension of the master list that has a boolean field indicating whether the item in the master list is contained in the `selList`.

I'm thinking that I'm somewhere along the lines of the Visitor pattern.

```
 public class SelectionCriteria<T> : where T : class
 {
    public IList<T> EligibleList { get; private set; }
    public IList LookupList { get; private set; }
 }
 LookupList = new List<object>
              {
                  new { ID = "fid", DESC = "Record 1"},
                  new { ID = "Record2", DESC = "Record 2"},
                  new { ID = "Record3", DESC = "Record 3"},
                  new { ID = "Record4", DESC = "Record 4"},
              };
  EligibleList = new List<AssetClass>
                 {
                     new AssetClass { FEE_ID = "fid", ASSET_CLASS = "A" },
                 };
```

I should get the following results:

```
  LookupList[0] == true
  LookupList[1] == false
  LookupList[2] == false
  LookupList[3] == false
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: What does *extension of the master list* means?

Comment: Why is `LookupList` a list of anonymous object as opposed to just a list of the ID values.  Keep in mind that once you put an anonymous type into a `List<object>` you've practically given up all useful aspects of it; you almost certainly should be doing something else, such as using a named type (or, in this case, just storing the string ID value).

Answer (score 2):

```
var results = LookupList.Select(l => EligibleList.Any(e => e.FEE_ID==l.ID))
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: This won't compile, as is, with the collections he's using.  It's also a bad idea to do a linear search on a `List` inside of a loop; virtually any time you do that it's better to put the items you're searching for into a collection that can be more effectively searched, such as a `Dictionary` or `HashSet`.

Comment: Right now the goal is to just to get it working, then get it on the optimization.  I was actually on the right track with the IVisitor concept, that using (dynamic) as a casting to a TypeSpecific method implementation would call the right method.

Comment: It really wouldn't matter what the base type of the lookup list is in the long run, for the original question.  I had a class that was being handed 2 lists.  Whether they were dictionaries or hashsets, I still had very limited knowledge of the collections to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Using this as a definition for `SelectionCriteria<T>`

```
public class SelectionCriteria<T>
    where T : class
{
    public IList<T> EligibleList { get; private set; }
    public IList LookupList { get; private set; }

    public SelectionCriteria(IList lookupList, IList<T> eligibleList)
    {
        LookupList = lookupList;
        EligibleList = eligibleList;
    }

    public bool this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            var element = LookupList[index];

            foreach (var item in EligibleList)
            {
                if (item.Equals(element))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this as a definition for `AssetClass`

```
public class AssetClass : IEquatable<AssetClass>
{
    public string FEE_ID { get; set; }

    public string ASSET_CLASS { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(AssetClass other)
    {
        return !ReferenceEquals(other, null) && other.FEE_ID == FEE_ID && other.ASSET_CLASS == ASSET_CLASS;
    }

    //Check to see if obj is a value-equal instance of AssetClass, if it's not, proceed
    //  to doing some reflection checks to determine value-equality
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as AssetClass) || PerformReflectionEqualityCheck(obj);
    }

    //Here's where we inspect whatever other thing we're comparing against
    private bool PerformReflectionEqualityCheck(object o)
    {
        //If the other thing is null, there's nothing more to do, it's not equal
        if (ReferenceEquals(o, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        //Get the type of whatever we got passed
        var oType = o.GetType();
        //Find the ID property on it
        var oID = oType.GetProperty("ID");

        //Get the value of the property
        var oIDValue = oID.GetValue(o, null);

        //If the property type is string (so that it matches the type of FEE_ID on this class
        //   and the value of the strings are equal, then we're value-equal, otherwise, we're not
        return oID.PropertyType == typeof (string) && FEE_ID == (string) oIDValue;
    }
}
```

You can get elements that are found in the list of eligible items that exist in the list of lookup items like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < assetClassSelectionCriteria.LookupList.Count; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("LookupList[{0}] == {1}", i, assetClassSelectionCriteria[i]);
}
```

You could also use the following for `PerformReflectionEqualityCheck` in `AssetClass` if you don't like seeing the reflection goodness

```
private bool PerformReflectionEqualityCheck(object o)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(o, null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    dynamic d = o;

    try
    {
        return FEE_ID == (string) d.ID;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If by "extension of the master list" you meant an extension method, then, instead of declaring an indexer on `SelectionCriteria<T>` to get the results, you could do something like this:

```
public static class SelectionCriteriaExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLookupItemEligible<T>(this SelectionCriteria<T> set, int index)
        where T : class
    {
        var element = set.LookupList[index];

        foreach (var item in set.EligibleList)
        {
            if (item.Equals(element))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
assetClassSelectionCriteria.IsLookupItemEligible(0);
```